# Class having a member of same class type

Tags: c#, c++

I have the following code in C++ which does not compile:

```
class Container;
class Container
{
    std::string m_Name;
    Container m_Container;
};
```

This is because I have a member with the same type and the compiler cannot infer the size of the object here.

What makes this work using C# ?

```
namespace Sample
{
    public class Container
    {
        public string m_Name;
        public Container m_Container;
    }
}

namespace Sample
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Container con = new Container();

        }
    }
}
```

This compiles fine in C#. How is the size of the object been calculated here ?

Comment: In C#, you would experience this pain with a struct. `struct C { C c; }`, for example.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The fact that it works in *C#* is that all objects are handled as pointers. That is, your C# code would be equivalent to this *C++* code:

```
class Container;
class Container
{
    std::string* m_Name;
    Container* m_Container;
};
```

The size of a pointer is known, and hence everything compiles. There is no need to know the size of the object at all. However, you don't want to go throwing pointers around in *C++*, specially raw pointers.

Note that in your original implementation, the size of the object not only is unknown but its also infinite since each `Container` contains another `Container` which contains another `Container` and so on...